# Angular ng-include controller inside another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a situation where I have one Angular controller, which basically just loads html templates depending on a click event. However, these templates are governed by there own controllers. This results in a controller being **inside** the original controller, which seems just wrong:

```
<div ng-controller="WindowCtrl" id="focus-window">

    <button ng-click="openProjects()">Show Projects</button>
    <button ng-click="openTasks()">Show Tasks</button>
    <div ng-include src="template.url"></div>

</div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('WindowCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.templates = [
        {
        name: 'tasks',
        url: 'partials/_tasks.html'},
    {
        name: 'projects',
        url: 'partials/_projects.html'}
    ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.openProjects = function() {
        $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
    };
    $scope.openTasks = function() {
        $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    };
});
```

**_projects.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl">
  <h2>My Projects</h2>
  ...            
</div>
```

**_tasks.html**

```
<div ng-controller="TasksCtrl">
  <h2>My Tasks</h2>
  ...            
</div>
```

My question is, what is the best solution for what I am trying to do without causing conflicting scopes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I actually think your method is correct.  I base this on the AngularJS documentation for [controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) (the "Demo" section shows a simple nested controller hierarchy in action).

Further, this seems pretty similar to how the form directive works.  It creates a scope for the form itself, evaluating $pristine, $dirty, $valid and $invalid for the overall form.  Those values are only true if all its sub-scopes evaluate to true as well (in other words, a form is only $valid if all inputs return as $valid as well).  This is done via a nested scope hierarchy, so if Angular does it in a fundamental way, then an application can do it similarly.

Comment: Although...if you're NOT tied to having these remain on the same page, you also could consider just routing each click to a different URL, since Angular makes it seem like the user is on the same page anyways.

Comment: The issue is I already have routing doing other dynamic loads of content. To do so here and keep track of state of the other parts seems like it would get real complicated quickly. If nested controllers isn't a sin *per se* then I will go with that and keep the `WindowCtrl` as simple as possible.